# Using Hashing Function in Unordered Set for User-Defined Class

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I hope you are all doing well.

I am currently working on a DFA-Implementation in C++ (looking to use it in order to write a lexer later on). I am still very bad at this, so forgive me if my question sounds stupid.

I have two main classes. A FSM (finite state machine) class which naturally contains states, transitions, and an alphabet. I chose to represent the transitions my set of states with an unordered_set of class State in order to avoid duplicate later.
I am aware that I have to write my own hashing function and my own equality comparator function, which I attempted to do in the following code. However, I have an endless stream of unredeable errors which seem to be linked to those two things that I just implemented.

FSM.h

```
#ifndef FSM_H
#define FSM_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "state.h"
#include <unordered_set>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
namespace std
{
        template<>
            class hash<State>
            {
            public:
                    size_t operator() (const State &state) const
                    {
                        return std::hash<std::string>()(state.name);
                    }
            };
}

struct isEqual
{
        bool operator() (const State& lhs, const State& rhs)
        {
            return (lhs.name == rhs.name);
        }
};
class FSM
{
        FSM() = default;
        FSM(State, 
        std::unordered_set<State>, 
        std::unordered_set<State>,std::unordered_set<std::tuple<State, std::string, State>>, 
        std::unordered_set<std::string>);
        ~FSM();
        State initialState; 
        std::unordered_set<std::string> alphabet;
        std::unordered_set<State> states;
        State init;
        std::unordered_set<State> finalStates;
        std::unordered_set<std::tuple<State,std::string,State>> transitions; //(CurrentState + input -> Next State)
        State currentState;
};
#endif
```

As you might see, I used over-specialization for the hashing in the namespace std.
As for the State Class, for now, it is the following:

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H
#include <string>

class State
{
public:
        State(std::string _name) {name = _name;}
        ~State();
        std::string name;
        bool operator ==(const State& rhs) const 
        {
            return (name == rhs.name);
        }
};

#endif
```

FSM.cpp

```
#include "fsm.h"
FSM::FSM(State _initialState,
std::unordered_set<State> _states,
std::unordered_set<State> _finalStates,
std::unordered_set<std::tuple<State,std::string,State>> _transitions,
std::unordered_set<std::string> _alphabet )
    {
        initialState = _initialState;
        states = _states;
        finalStates = _finalStates;
        transitions = _transitions;
        alphabet = _alphabet;
    }
```

Command to compile is as follows:
`c++ -std=c++11 -o testing *.cpp`

How could I fix my hashing function and/or my comparison equality function for it to work?

Any help will be very appreciated ! Thank you !!!

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: You also have a `std::unordered_set<std::tuple<State,std::string,State>> transitions`. Did you define a hash for the tuple too? Also, though that is the set-theory way of defining it, you might want a `std::unordered_map<State, std::unordered_map<std::string, State>> transitions` (transitions[currentState][input] -> nextState)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for pointing this out. Just edited the question.
And Artyer, I did not write a hash for the other unordered_set. And as for your suggestion, I actually was about to try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is below:

```
FSM(State, 
        std::unordered_set<State>, 
        std::unordered_set<State>,std::unordered_set<std::tuple<State, std::string, State>>, 
        std::unordered_set<std::string>);
        ~FSM();
        void addTransition(std::tuple<State,std::string,State >);
        void deleteTransition(std::tuple<State,std::string,State>);
        void addState(State _state);
        void deleteState(State);
        void newAlphabet();
        void addTransition();
        void input(std::string input);
        void setCurrentState(State);
        void setInitialState (State);
        void setFinalStates(std::unordered_set<State> );
        void setTransitions(std::unordered_set<std::tuple<State,std::string,State>>);
        void setStates(std::unordered_set<State> );

        State initialState; 
        std::unordered_set<std::string> alphabet;
        std::unordered_set<State> states;
        State init;
        std::unordered_set<State> finalStates;
        std::unordered_set<std::tuple<State,std::string,State>> transitions; //(CurrentState + input -> Next State)
        State currentState;
```

You declared a lot of functions but you never defined them, so the compiler does not recongize them....

Comment: Thank you for the comment. As @JeJo pointed out the possibility of it, I actually did define these functions in its own .cpp file. The reason I did not include them is because I thought they would not be relevant. I did not respect the minimal reproducible example guideline, and I apologize for this. This is my first time asking, so I will edit my question so that you folks can see it. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @JeJo Just updated the question ! Let me know if any additional info is needed